# pyodbc Error: 'HY090', Invalid string or buffer length (0)

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

**Purpose:**

Utilizing the `read_sql_query()` and `to_sql()` methods of `pandas`, the goal of my `python 3.7` script was to perform an ETL of multiple tables from one server to another by reading a `.sql` file. The connection parameter in both methods utilizes the `create_engine` module of `sqlalchemy`.

**Error Raised:**

After successfully extracting and loading the first set of tables+transactions, the 4th errors out.

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY090', '[HY090] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Please see below for further details.

**Procedure:**

- Each extracted table is written as a SQL transaction split by `;` in one SQL file.

```
    'ExtractTables.sql'

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT 
        [ID1]       
    ,   [Name]          
    ,   [LastUpdated]   
    ,   [UpdatedBy]     

    INTO #table1
    FROM DB1.dbo.table1 

    SELECT * FROM #table1

    ;

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT 
        [ID1]
    ,   [ID2]
    ,   [Descr]

    INTO #table2 FROM DB1.dbo.table2

    SELECT * FROM #table2
```

- ODBC parameters are setup for engines with the `create_engine` module for each server. Both servers are MS-SQL servers. From my research, I believe my error is coming from the `fast_executemany` parameter.

```
    'connection.py'

    import pyodbc
    import urllib
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine

    #Use trusted connection to connect to server. fast_executemany is mssql specific. Allows for large data loads.

    params_H = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=SERVER1;DATABASE=DB1;Trusted_Connection=yes")
    engine_H = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params_H}', fast_executemany=True)


    params_b = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=SERVER2;DATABASE=DB2;Trusted_Connection=yes")
    engine_b= create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params_b}', fast_executemany=True)
```

- Python Script to iterate over each command and use `read_sql_query()` for each command to extract, and `to_sql()` to load each table.

```
    'LoadTables.py'

    import pandas as pd
    import conn


    def readSQLFile_makeTables(filename):
        # Open and read file
        open_file = open(filename, 'r')
        sql_file = open_file.read()
        open_file.close()

        #all SQL commands (split on ';')
        sql_commands = sql_file.split(';')


        # Execute every command from file
        sql_tables = ['stg_table1', 'stg_table2', 'stg_table3']

        i = 0
        for command in sql_commands:

            table = pd.read_sql_query(command, con=conn.engine_H)
            print(table)
            table.to_sql(sql_tables[i], con=conn.engine_b, chunksize=5000, index=False, if_exists='append')
            i += 1

        print('think this ran')
```

**Error:**

For the purposes of StackOverflow I limited my sql code to 2 batches, however it has 4. The first 3 successfully pass the read and the write. However the fourth raises the error on the write. The primary difference in the error table batch versus the rest is its size (7 million rows x 8 columns) and the next highest being (1.5 million x 6 columns).

**Troubleshooting:**

All errors I've research on this topic point to it being an issue with the ODBC connection. Both servers are 64-bit, I'm utilizing pydobc 4.025, and I've tested only extracting fields of integer values. The first transactions being able to load successfully tells me the majority is working, but the last one has an issue preventing the load. I'm assuming size, which I believe is handled by `chunksize=5000` and `fast_executemany = true`, and the error pointing back to a binding parameter.

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/548

**Traceback:**

```
    [6721864 rows x 8 columns]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1244, in _execute_context
        cursor, statement, parameters, context
      File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 552, in do_execute
        cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    pyodbc.Error: ('HY090', '[HY090] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "PYTHON\Testing\ETL\LoadTables.py", line 21, in readSQLFile_makeTables
        table = pd.read_sql_query(command, con=conn.engine_H)
      File "\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 314, in read_sql_query
        parse_dates=parse_dates, chunksize=chunksize)
      File "\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1063, in read_query
        result = self.execute(*args)
      File "\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 954, in execute
        return self.connectable.execute(*args, **kwargs)
      File "\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2166, in execute
        return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
      File "\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 982, in execute
        return self._execute_text(object_, multiparams, params)
      File "\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1155, in _execute_text
        parameters,
      File "\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
        e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
      File "\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1466, in _handle_dbapi_exception
        util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
      File "\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 383, in raise_from_cause
        reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
      File "\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 128, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1244, in _execute_context
        cursor, statement, parameters, context
      File "\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 552, in do_execute
        cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY090', '[HY090] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
    (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)
```

Comment: sounds like it could be that the driver is 32 bits running on 64 bits systems, can you confirm?

Comment: I'm unsure if the engine I reference in `pyodbc` or `sqlaclhemy` utilizes 32 bits. However in my ODBC Data Source Administrator, the System DSN has both platforms showing as 64bit.

Comment: Confirmed that python is 64-bit, assuming the packages (`pyodbc`) installed are as well.

Comment: I'm unable to tell. Under User DSN it shows the extracting data source platform as  32/64 bit , and driver as ODBC Driver 17. Under the System DSN it shows 64 bit for the platform, and ODBC Driver 17 for driver. The loading datasource is showing 64 bit as the platform for both.

Comment: Hey, I've run into what seems to be pretty much this exact issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Rob, I believe it was due to having a ‘;’ at the end of my last sql query. This caused split to append a blank value to the commands list, and fail on table.to_sql()

Comment: Thanks @hSin, in my case I had multiple sql executions, previous execution ran, except the 3rd one. Therefore, it could never of been a 64 or 32 bit issue.

Comment: In the python execution script , each execution is split on the word "GO" in the sql script, the last line of the sql script  had a "GO". Once this was remove, the problem was resolved.

Comment: @Sade More information regarding GO and where it can be included can be found at ending link. GO is a SSMS command, and not a Transact-SQL.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular issue in my case was having an extra `;` at the end of my sql file which caused `sql_file.split(';')` to cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through a similar problem. what happened was that when transferring the data to pyodbc some data had information with incorrect formatting or not supported by pyodb. the solution was to transfer the data to CSV and get pyodbc to take the Data from the CSV

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the datatype for columns with `cursor.setinputsizes`. And set VARCHAR type to INT, FLOAT or DateTime columns.

```
cursor.setinputsizes([(pyodbc.SQL_VARCHAR, 50, 0), ...])
```

This mistake caused by `fast_executemany = True`. It has to do with some magic with memory. These articles will help https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/520, https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/pull/729